# Some or all of the X -vs- some or all the X

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

A rule can apply to none, some, or all the packets.

~vs~

A rule can apply to none, some, or all of the packets.

Which form is more appropriate?

I am writing a document and can't seem to decide which is correct. Packet refers to network packets (like the data units of an internet connection) and rule refers to firewall rules which decide whether to allow/block certain kinds of network traffic.

Comment: Note that in the *exact* example cited, the word ***of*** is effectively *optional* (it's syntactically valid with or without ***of***). But if the "list" was reordered to *A rule can apply to none, all, or some of the packets* OR *A rule can apply to some, all, or none of the packets*, then it wouldn't be syntactically valid to omit ***of*** (because ***none*** and ***some*** have different syntactic affordances to ***all***).

Comment: Note that a Google Internet search returns twice as many hits for  prepositionless ["fool all the people"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fool+all+the+people%22&oq=%22fool+all+the+people%22&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60.2180j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) as it does for ["fool all **of** the people"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fool+all+of+the+people%22&oq=%22fool+all+of+the+people%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.4644j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever kind of packets they are, you need to include the *of,* which applies to all three pronouns. (You can't say 'none the packets'.)

Comment: You can't say 'none the packets' or 'some the packets', but you *can* say '**all** [of] the packets' with or without the preposition, so *something* doesn't apply to all three pronouns..